# What probability analysis did the allies use during WWII after they cracked the Enigma, or how can this probability be quantified?

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling, popular-math

In the recent film, The Imitation Game, after cracking the Enigma they mentioned that the allies didn't simply use every cracked message but instead analysed the probability the Germans would find out their codes were broken. My question is how?

How is it possible to quantify the probability of the Germans suspecting something is wrong by intercepting a submarine or some other German military unit?

Comment: I would assume the analysis has to take place for each individual message. You would have to determine in what ways could this particular information have been obtained, and then quantify each one of these from the enemy perspective. If the enemy thinks you are acting on information that only could have been obtained from a message in their code, they can be certain their code is broken. If there are more ways, then we have to quantify a probability somehow: the method how would have to be unique to each case.

Comment: You'd probably do better posting this on the History of Math and Science SE site at http://hsm.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @rogerl well I'm also interested in how can such a thing can be done so an example for the analysis would be welcomed. Even how it would be done today.

Comment: initially data and analysis about the [enigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) was done in Polland by a team of Polish mathematicians, then this knowledge was transferred to UK where Turing and others [worked on the problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis_of_the_Enigma) in Bletchley Park, there is even a wiki book on the enigma story

Comment: @NikosM. yes but I'm not asking about the Enigma but about the probability/statistical analysis done on the cracked messages. I couldn't find anything about it online.